# Como obtener la hora actual a través de internet en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio y necesito obtener la hora a la que los usuarios inician sesión. Se que hay una forma de obtener la hora del terminal pero esto no me basta ya que si un usuario tiene la hora del terminal mal, aparecería esta hora. Gracias!

Comment: Hola David. ¿Qué es lo que has probado o intentado? ¿Te ha dado fallos? ¿Dónde? ¿Vas a coger la hora de un servidor que gestionas tú o te vale otro? Hace falta que edites tu pregunta para dar más información y que te podamos ayudar. Mira [ask] y rehaz tu pregunta cumpliendo las normas del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una libreria de Apache ([Apache Commnons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)) para esto. Te la puedes descargar desde este [enlace](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsnet33jar.htm).

E insertas el siguiente código:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.time.TimeTCPClient;

public final class GetTime {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
            try {
                // Set timeout of 60 seconds
                client.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
                // Connecting to time server
                // Other time servers can be found at : http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi#
                // Make sure that your program NEVER queries a server more frequently than once every 4 seconds
                client.connect("time.nist.gov");
                System.out.println(client.getDate());
            } finally {
                client.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Como podras comprobar, te escribirá la hora en la consola

Comment: No debería usarse esta clase ya que **Las librerías apache son obsoletas en Android Studio**